# New Relic Java Agent error 401

Tags: java, tomcat, newrelic

I am using NewRelic on a AWS Linux machine and a Java Application on TomCat. The logs of NewRelic are fine, and my application appears on NewRelics's website. The problem is my data is not being sent. I always see the error "An error occurred posting metric data - Received a 401 response from collector-182.newrelic.com.  This data will be resent later." on the log file.

Does anybody know how to solve this? My license key is right.

Comment: If you are absolutely certain that your license key is right AND if you have [given sufficient time for the agent to recover and retransmit](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/an-error-occurred-posting-metric-data/51306) AND have given time for that data to appear in APM AND have followed the [No data appears (Java)](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/troubleshooting/no-data-appears-java) help document, then you should [contact New Relic support](https://support.newrelic.com/) for further assistance.

Comment: A really simple test is to create a new app, include New Relic with its default configuration, then run the app and see if it can successfully transmit. That would rule out any issue with your account (billing or subscription), your license key, and your network, and would indicate the problem is possibly with the agent configuration for your first app. (are you doing too much custom instrumentation and trying to transmit too much data to New Relic?)